# How do I get my output which is json converted in a dataframe format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, typeerror

Im new to python and trying to format my output from an API:

The output dataframe is:

```
**data**
Out[8]: b'[{"date":"2020-01-19","stats":[{"metrics":{"blocks":5,"bounce_drops":6,"bounces":16,"clicks":278,"deferred":8,"delivered":1453,"invalid_emails":6,"opens":2502,"processed":155,"requests":1484,"spam_report_drops":0,"spam_reports":0,"unique_clicks":199,"unique_opens":1013,"unsubscribe_drops":0,"unsubscribes":0}}]}]\n'
```

I want to make this in tabular form so that I can export it to a csv:

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
merge_HOO = {'blocks': [], 'bounce_drops': [], 'bounces': [], 'clicks': []}
for i, restaurant in enumerate(data):
    for item in restaurant['metrics']:
        merge_HOO['blocks'].append(i)
        merge_HOO['bounce_drops'].append(item['bounce_drops'])
        merge_HOO['bounces'].append(item['bounces'])
        merge_HOO['clicks'].append(item['clicks'])


merge_HOO = pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO,
                         columns=['blocks', 'bounce_drops', 'bounces', 'clicks'])
print(merge_HOO)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-ad0eecd65eba>", line 4, in <module>
    for item in restaurant['metrics']:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

But I got the above error.

I want it to look like the below in my csv where i have the resepective headers and the stats below each:

```
blocks bounce_drops  bounces
5       6             16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# lets say d is your list containing dict
f = json_normalize(d)

# reshape the data
cols = ['blocks','bounce_drops','bounces']
df = f['stats'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))['metrics'].apply(pd.Series)[cols]

   blocks  bounce_drops  bounces
0       5             6       16
```

**Sample Data**

```
d = [{"date":"2020-01-19","stats":[{"metrics":{"blocks":5,"bounce_drops":6,"bounces":16,"clicks":278,"deferred":8,"delivered":1453,"invalid_emails":6,"opens":2502,"processed":155,"requests":1484,"spam_report_drops":0,"spam_reports":0,"unique_clicks":199,"unique_opens":1013,"unsubscribe_drops":0,"unsubscribes":0}}]}]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values' @yolo this gives an error.

Comment: I added the sample data I used for the solution, make sure your data is in this format. It's a list containing a dict.

Comment: for x in compat.itervalues(y)] for y in data):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable is this error because there are more variables to convert to the dataframe?

Comment: what is the structure of your data ? Is it not same as `d` ?

Comment: it is same as d. if i run d = print(data.decode("utf-8"))
[{"date":"2020-01-19","stats":[{"metrics":{"blocks":5,"bounce_drops":6,"bounces":16,"clicks":278,"deferred":8,"delivered":1453,"invalid_emails":6,"opens":2502,"processed":155,"requests":1484,"spam_report_drops":0,"spam_reports":0,"unique_clicks":199,"unique_opens":1013,"unsubscribe_drops":0,"unsubscribes":0}}]}]

Comment: hmm interesting, I ran it again and it worked, which pandas version are you on?

Comment: pd.__version__
Out[26]: '0.24.2'

Comment: when I run the command of print(data.decode("ut-8") thats when I get the output of the dictionary as I pasted above. WHat I did next is set it as "d" and then ran the script you provided but I still got the Nonetype error

Comment: my pandas is 0.25.3, you mind upgrading your version, `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: if I run 
print(d)
None  Could this be the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206301/discussion-between-hartville-zillow-and-yolo).

Answer (score 0):

You missed a list, in the error `item` resolves to `list` in `stats`

```
File "<ipython-input-9-ad0eecd65eba>", line 4, in <module>
    for item in restaurant['metrics']:
```

You don't need pandas just to output csv, just use `csv` module.
Assuming JSON is dicts in a list:

```
import csv, io

j = [{
        "date": "2020-01-19",
        "stats": [
                    { "metrics":{
                                "blocks": 5,
                                "bounce_drops": 6,
                                "bounces": 16,
                                "clicks": 278,
                                "deferred": 8,
                                "delivered": 1453,
                                "invalid_emails": 6,
                                "opens": 2502,
                                "processed": 155,
                                "requests": 1484,
                                "spam_report_drops": 0,
                                "spam_reports": 0,
                                "unique_clicks": 199,
                                "unique_opens": 1013,
                                "unsubscribe_drops": 0,
                                "unsubscribes": 0
                                }
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-18",
        "stats": [
                    { "metrics":{
                                "blocks": 5,
                                "bounce_drops": 6,
                                "bounces": 16,
                                "clicks": 278,
                                "deferred": 8,
                                "delivered": 1453,
                                "invalid_emails": 6,
                                "opens": 2502,
                                "processed": 155,
                                "requests": 1484,
                                "spam_report_drops": 0,
                                "spam_reports": 0,
                                "unique_clicks": 199,
                                "unique_opens": 1013,
                                "unsubscribe_drops": 0,
                                "unsubscribes": 0
                                }
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-17",
        "stats": [
                    { "metrics":{
                                "blocks": 5,
                                "bounce_drops": 6,
                                "bounces": 16,
                                "clicks": 278,
                                "deferred": 8,
                                "delivered": 1453,
                                "invalid_emails": 6,
                                "opens": 2502,
                                "processed": 155,
                                "requests": 1484,
                                "spam_report_drops": 0,
                                "spam_reports": 0,
                                "unique_clicks": 199,
                                "unique_opens": 1013,
                                "unsubscribe_drops": 0,
                                "unsubscribes": 0
                                }
                    }
                ]
    }]

merged = {'blocks': 0, 'bounce_drops': 0, 'bounces': 0, 'clicks': 0}

for i, d in enumerate(j):
    for lst in d['stats']:
        metrics = lst['metrics']
        merged['blocks']       += metrics['blocks']
        merged['bounce_drops'] += metrics['bounce_drops']
        merged['bounces']      += metrics['bounces']
        merged['clicks']       += metrics['clicks']

print(merged)
# {'blocks': 15, 'bounce_drops': 18, 'bounces': 48, 'clicks': 834}
```

to test before writing to file use `io.StringIO`

```
result = io.StringIO(initial_value='', newline='\n')
fieldnames = list(merged.keys())
writer = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(merged)
print(result.getvalue())
# blocks,bounce_drops,bounces,clicks
# 15,18,48,834
```

if you insist on using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(merged, index=[0])
csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
print(csv)
# 'blocks,bounce_drops,bounces,clicks\n15,18,48,834\n'
```